# How to express "content" in a book or in what other said

Tags: word-usage

I have a question about how native speakers would refer to the "content" in a book or in what other mentioned. For example, if I want to say "the content in the book is great." or "I didn't understand the content in the previous conversation". Is the word "content" OK or there are other better words to express that meaning?

Comment: We speak of the content _of_ a book. However, I think most people would just say that a _book_ is good (unless you specify the cover design or something, it's obvious that you mean its content).   Similarly, "I didn't understand/couldn't follow that conversation".

Comment: Use of content is correct. However I would use "the content [of] the book is great." or "the content [in] the book is great.";  and "I didn't understand the content of the previous conversation".

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

We use "***the content of** the book*" rather than just "*the book*" when there's some other aspect of the book to contrast it with.

It could be like the style, the language, the art, or the font size, as in:

> The style of writing in that book is terrible, but the content is great.

In that kind of context, "content" is correct and natural.

Comment: Got it, my friend, thanks for your help!! However, I am still wondering how people express the following, "the speech or what one said is good in everything but content"(Referring to the key meaning). I can't find a word or expression to substitute the meaning of content

Comment: @Dada What's wrong with the word "content"? Why do you need a substitute?

Comment: :I am sorry my friend. I misunderstood a sentence in a comment and thought I couldn't use content with words like "conversation"  "talks" . I was wrong. Now I got it. : )))